# Adding an action widget to Gtk# notebook

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

Is it possible to add an action area widget to a Gtk# 2 notebook? I do not see any methods similar to the C API function `gtk_notebook_set_action_widget`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I found that `gtk_notebook_set_action_widget()` [was added v2.20 of Gtk+2](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkNotebook.html#gtk-notebook-set-action-widget), while Mono is stuck in v2.12.

Anyway, you can simulate action buttons creating an appropriate Box. Is that what you want?